# Where is the system call handler for pause() system call?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I could find the declartion and also entry in syscall_table, but i couldn't find any definitions for any architecture.

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/include/linux/syscalls.h#L384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's defined in `kernel/signal.c`:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(pause)
{
    while (!signal_pending(current)) {
        current->state = TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE;

    /* .... */
```